# Angular JS category filter not working recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I'm developing a file filter based on angular js. Now I'm facing an issue while filtering results based on categories and the respective sub categories. If I select a category id=a then the files assigned to category a and its descendant subcategories also should be shown. Any one please help me to sort it out. Here are the details. 
[ -- So far I fixed the category filtering issue, Now the problem is whenever I select the drop down filter it clears and showing the results correctly. Please help me to fix it. I've updated the code in plunker **http://plnkr.co/edit/fzOzms?p=preview**]

### JSON

[View JSON Input](http://111.93.236.161:9000/public/tntgraphics/assets_html/v1.0/data.json)

http://plnkr.co/edit/fzOzms?p=preview

### HTML

```
<div class="filter-wrapper" ng-controller="filterCtrl">
            <div class="filter-wrap">
                <form action="" class="filter">
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="control-label">{{items.transilations.keywordsearch}}</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search" ng-change="filter()" placeholder="{{items.transilations.searchkey}}">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="search = ''"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="control-label">{{items.transilations.filterbyarea}}</label>                   
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <custom-select ng-repeat="cat in categories track by $index" class="inline-table" style="display:table;"></custom-select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="control-label">{{items.transilations.searchbytype}}</label>
                        <div ng-repeat="type in items.types">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkFilter[type.id]" value="{{type.id}}">
                                {{type.title}}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="result-wrap">
                <h3><span id="total-count"></span> {{items.transilations.resultsfound}}</h3>
                <table id="data-results" class="results">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th class="item-title">
                                <a href="" ng-click="orderByField='title'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                                    {{items.transilations.tabletitle}} 
                                    <span ng-show="orderByField == 'title'">
                                        <span ng-show="!reverseSort"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></span>
                                        <span ng-show="reverseSort"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </th>                   
                            <th>
                                <a href="" ng-click="orderByField='size'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                                    {{items.transilations.tablesize}}
                                    <span ng-show="orderByField == 'size'">
                                        <span ng-show="!reverseSort"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></span>
                                        <span ng-show="reverseSort"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <a href="" ng-click="orderByField='fileType'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                                    {{items.transilations.tabletype}}
                                    <span ng-show="orderByField == 'fileType'">
                                        <span ng-show="!reverseSort"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></span>
                                        <span ng-show="reverseSort"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </th>
                            <th class="download">{{items.transilations.tabledownload}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr dir-paginate ="file in items.files | filter:dummyCategory | filter:byTypes | filter:search |  orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort | offset:0 | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">
                            <td class="item-image" data-th="Image"><img class="img-thumbnail" ng-src="{{base}}{{file.imageUrl}}"></td>
                            <td class="item-title" data-th="{{items.transilations.tabletitle}}">{{file.title}}</td>                 
                            <td data-th="{{items.transilations.tablesize}}">{{file.size}}</td>
                            <td data-th="{{items.transilations.tabletype}}">{{file.fileType}}</td>
                            <td class="download" data-th="{{items.transilations.tabledownload}}"><a target="_blank" ng-href="http://192.168.0.207/usterch/{{file.url}}"><img src="save.png"/></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="other-controller">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)" template-url="js/dirPagination/dirPagination.tpl.html">
                    </dir-pagination-controls>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

### Angular JS Code

```
app.directive("subcat", function($compile, $timeout){
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        scope:true,
        link:function(scope,element,attr){
            element.bind("change",function($index){ 
                $timeout(function(){
                    scope.dummyCategory.categories = [scope.dummyCategory.categories];
                    $(element).children('option:selected').attr('data-newVal', scope.dummyCategory.categories);
                    $(element).children('option:selected').attr('data-resetClear', JSON.stringify(scope.dummyCategory));
                    if(scope.dummyCategory.categories == null){
                        if($(element).parent().prev('custom-select').length){
                            scope.dummyCategory.categories= $(element).parent().prev('custom-select').find('option:selected').attr('data-newVal');
                        }
                        else{
                            scope.dummyCategory.categories="";
                        }
                    }
                    var newValue = scope.cat.val.filter(function(item)  {
                        return item.id == scope.dummyCategory.categories
                    });
                    if(newValue[0] && 'input' in newValue[0]){                      
                        getVal(scope, newValue[0]);
                        scope.newArray({categories:scope.dummyCategory,val:newValue[0].input,index:scope.$index});
                        element[0].blur();                      
                    }
                    else{
                        scope.removeArray(scope.$index);
                    }
                    scope.changeCat(scope.dummyCategory);
                }, 100, true);  
            });         
        }
    }
});

function getVal(scope, newValue){   
    var testArray = {testval:newValue.input};   
    var tvLength = testArray.testval.length;
    for(var i=0; i<tvLength; i++){
        scope.dummyCategory.categories.push(testArray.testval[i].id);
        if(testArray.testval[i].input){
            getVal(scope, testArray.testval[i]);
        }   
    }
    return scope.dummyCategory.categories;
}
```

[Server Link](http://111.93.236.161:9000/public/tntgraphics/assets_html/v1.0/filter.html)

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/3YCTRsKxQ05cuy3czTIb?p=preview

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: @Sam: AngularJS v1.3.14

Comment: A bit busy at the moment, but I suggest you use a function as a filter, which will enable you to return child elements too. See here for an example: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgYzze
You could also speed up your filters by using this: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#filterby

Comment: I've already met such thing, may you put the full example on Plunker?

Comment: @Raeef: http://plnkr.co/edit/fzOzms?p=preview . So Far I did up to this. Now the issue is whenever I try to filter the checkbox clears automatically please help me to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Angular filter instead of creating a directive, and here is an example:

JSON:

```
{
    categories: [{
        id: 1
        name: "cat1"
    }, {
        id: 2
        name: "cat2"
    }]

    files: [{
        id: 1,
        cat_id: 1,
        name: "file1"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        cat_id: 1,
        name: "file2"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        cat_id: 2,
        name: "file3"
    }, {
        id: 4,
        cat_id: 2,
        name: "file1"
    }]
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="ExampleApp" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
    <select ng-model="cat_id" ng-options="cat.id as cat.name for cat in categories">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="file_id" ng-options="file.id as file.name for file in files | filter:{cat_id: cat_id}:comparator">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])

.controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.comparator = function(actual, expected) {
        // comparison here is '==' which is not the same as angular comparison '===', because sometimes the data type is not equal
        return actual == expected;
    };
}]);
```

and of course you can add filters as it's needed to fit your app.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer I'll check and revert.

Comment: Refal: Can you explain how the child of a category is considered in filtering. I mean if cat id 1 has child with cat id 4,5. If I select category 1 then filter should consider 1,4,5 categories in filtering the files.

Comment: mmmmm. well, your example is more complex than I've provided and honestly I don't have enough time to make it for you, but it's still possible to make it with filter, by pushing each sub category id to an array when selected and remove it when changing its parent, then filtering files according to the array which contains the category and its children IDs. Hope it helps.

Comment: Refal: Actually I know well the logic you've explained. But the issue is I dont know how to implement it in Angular JS. Can you please show me any other examples.